# 2010s young adult fantasy book about a teenager who goes to live in a mansion and a young relative who watches an evil TV show

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I think he moved to the New England area. I remember him having magical powers and living in a mansion. If I recall correctly, there was a younger relative (maybe a cousin) who watched this evil TV show or there was an evil character who infiltrated the show to gain control of the boy.

I really want to pick this series up again, but can't remember the name. I do remember the author's last name would have begun with an A, B, or C, because it was in that section of the library. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

As confirmed by the OP via [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263368/2010s-young-adult-fantasy-book-about-a-teenager-who-goes-to-live-in-a-mansion-an/263369#comment725853_263369), this is ***[Sorcerers of the Nightwing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/345966.Sorcerers_of_the_Nightwing)*** (2002) by Geoffrey Huntington.

From a [review](https://fantasyliterature.com/reviews/sorcerers-of-the-nightwing/):

> **After his father’s death, fourteen year old Devon March is sent to his new home in New England — the huge and forbidding mansion Ravenscliff**, that all the townspeople he meets on his way warn him against travelling to. But Devon is not as afraid of his future as others in his shoes would be: he knows he is gifted with a special power, a power that protected him from the very real demons and monsters that he had dwelling in his cupboard and under his bed as a child. Now, he seeks to find who he is, and why such things happen to him, for on his death bed, his father claimed he was not his biological father. Guided by the calm and powerful Voice in his head, that grants to him his own brand of magic, Devon is eager to begin his investigation.
>
> **At Ravenscliff are a host of intriguing characters waiting for him — the glamorous Mrs Crandall, his new guardian,** who undoubtably knows more than she’s saying, and her daughter Cecily, in whom Devon hopes to find a friend. As well as this is the unfriendly manservant Simon **and Mrs Crandell’s nephew Alexander— a violent and disfunctional boy who spends all his time watching a replusive clown on the television and seems to both hate and like Devon.** And on top of all this is Old Mrs Crandell, the somewhat senile old woman who’s spent several years in her bedroom, seeing no one but her daughter.
>
> And outside the grim seaside mansion is the elusive figure of Rolfe Montaigne, who has a connection to the house’s secrets and the death of two young people several years before. Mystery piles up upon mystery as **Devon learns of the many ghosts of the house — the weeping Emily Muir, the sad and tragic Horatio Muir, and the wicked Jackson Muir, whom Devon begins to suspect has a hold over the eight year old Alexander, who at times certainly seems like a boy possessed. And then some of the truth concerning his own destiny arises — he is part of the Order of the Nightwing, a powerful sect of sorcerers, a group of people chosen to be guardians over Hellholes: gateways from our world into hell. It is this newfound heritage that Devon will have to learn to master if he’s to triumph over the hold Jackson Muir now has over the house…**

Someone asked a [story-ID question about this novel on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19509745-solved-young-adult-book-about-two-boys-moving-into-a-haunted-mansion-w), and described the plot thusly:

> PLOT: **It had two boys moving into this mansion with their aunt or something. one of the boys discovers a TV room while exploring, every night he goes into that room and the TV is on, and someone is talking to him. I don't remember exactly what he talks about, but he turns out to be some sort of demon that needs children to live. the boy gets kidnapped by this man, and his brother has to search the house to find him.**

Comment: This is it exactly! Thank you so much!! I can't wait to revisit this book. 